# Converting paragraph tags with RegEx

Tags: php, regex

I need to replace all `<p>` tags with `<br />` tags within a string.
The problem is that the `<p>` tag can have attributes in it , such as `<p align="center">` so I want to delete all occurrences of an opening tag of a paragraph, no matter what attributes are in it, and replace them with `<br />`.

I am using PHP and had no success getting to the right expression with the `preg_replace` function.

Any help would be appreciated!

Joel

Comment: `<p( [a-zA-Z0-9= '"]+)?>` Could of work to catch all the inline attributes i think

Comment: This replaces occurrences of the letter "p" as well, anywhere in the string

Comment: No, it won't. Unless you forgot to use the required regex delimiters and PHP thought you wanted `<` and `>` to be the delimiters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
preg_replace('#<p\b[^>]*>#i', '<br />', $stringContainingParas)
```

The above should give you what you want. It matches any open angle bracket, then either a p or a P (it is case insensitive from the i following the closing delimiter), then zero or more characters that are not a closing angle bracket, and then finally the closing angle bracket.

```
preg_replace('#<p\b.*?>#i', '<br />', $stringContainingParas)
```

Will do just as good a job. Instead of matching any character that is not a closing angle bracket, it matches any character, but not greedily so that the closing angle bracket matches the next part of the regex if it is encountered anywhere along the line.

Comment: Watch out. This will replace all tags that start with `p` (for example `<pre>` tags).

Comment: @Tim That is certainly true. Your addition of the \b word boundary is needed. Updating.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you will never have a `>` inside an attribute to a `<p>` tag, you could do the following:

```
$result = preg_replace('/<p\b[^>]*>/s', '<br />', $subject);
```